# Group keys from a multidimensional don't show doubles and change their parent keys into child keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a hard time correctly formulating this question in the title so I will show you the situation. If you have a suggestion for a better title I'll change it.

I have the following array (an example, it can be any number of years/keys inside):

```
Array
(
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [Werkplek opgeruimd] => 6
            [Keuringsstickers op arbeidsmiddelen] => 1
            [Veilig gebruikte gereedschappen] => 2
            [Persoonlijke beschermingsmiddelen aanwezig, deugdelijk en juist] => 3
            [Veilige werkmethodes] => 3
        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [Veilig gebruikte gereedschappen] => 1
            [Persoonlijke beschermingsmiddelen aanwezig, deugdelijk en juist] => 2
            [Veilige werkmethodes] => 2
            [Werkplek opgeruimd] => 1
            [Materialen opslag veilig] => 1
        )

)
```

The array contains years, within those years it contains checklist questions, and the amount of times something was not OK as its value.

Which I want to pour into the following HTML markup (Only two questions added because it's an example):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Question</th>
         <th>2019</th>
         <th>2020</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Werkplek opgeruimd</td>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Keuringstickers op arbeidsmiddelen</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't think there is an easy way to get above result with the array I posted. So I want to change above array into this format:

```
Array
(
    [Werkplek opgeruimd] => Array
    (
        [2019] => 6
        [2020] => 1
    )

    [Persoonlijke beschermingsmiddelen aanwezig, deugdelijk en juist] => Array
    (
        [2019] => 3
        [2020] => 2
    )

    [Materialen opslag veilig] => Array
    (
        [2019] => 0
        [2020] => 1
    )
)
```

Get the questions from every year, only show them once with the years as keys in them and the numbers as value. Also display `0` for a year if the question does not appear.

I've tried getting the wanted output looping through everything but I'm wondering If I am missing a php function that would help with this?

Comment: No, I don’t think there is any native function that can get you that result in one go, the case is just too specific for that to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific function for this, but here is a relatively short method of doing it.  Assuming the above array is `$questions` (comments in code)...

```
$keys = [];
// Collect all questions from all years
foreach ( $questions as $year ) {
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($year));
}
$output = [];
// Loop over the unique questions
foreach ( array_unique($keys) as $key ) {
    // Loop over the years
    foreach ( $questions as $year => $values )  {
        // Set the number for this year (if not found, default to 0)
        $output [$key][$year] = $values[$key] ?? 0;
    }
}
```